# React , How to populate table once the React form is submitted with POST request , without having to refresh browser?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am doing this MERN CRUD application . There I have a form to add a book to the database. The AddBook.jsx is as follows.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import axios from "axios";

const Addbook = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState("");
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
    const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false); 

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:4040/api/books", {
        title,
        author,
        category,
        price,
      });

      console.log("Book added:", response.data);

      // Reset the form fields
      setTitle("");
      setAuthor("");
      setCategory("");
      setPrice("");

      // Show success toast
      toast.success("Book added successfully!");

      // Update submission status
      setSubmitted(true);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error adding book:", error);

      // Show error toast
      toast.error("Failed to add book.");
    }
  };
  if (submitted) {
    setSubmitted(false);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Add Book</h3>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
        <Form.Group controlId="title" className="mb-3">
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter title"
            value={title}
            onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
            required
          />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="author" className="mb-3">
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter author"
            value={author}
            onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)}
            required
          />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="category" className="mb-3">
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter category"
            value={category}
            onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}
            required
          />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="price" className="mb-3">
          <Form.Control
            type="number"
            placeholder="Enter price"
            value={price}
            onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}
            required
          />
        </Form.Group>

        <Button className="mt-3" variant="primary" type="submit">
          Add Book
        </Button>
      </Form>
      <ToastContainer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Addbook;
```

I have a table component where I populate data from the database.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Table, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:4040/api",
});

const BookTable = ({ books, updateBooks }) => {
  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    // Handle book deletion logic here
    console.log(`Deleting book with ID ${id}`);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ maxHeight: "400px", overflow: "auto" }}>
      <Table striped bordered hover>
        {/* Table headers */}
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {/* Table body */}
        <tbody>
          {books.map((book) => (
            <tr key={book.id}>
              {/* Table cells */}
              <td>{book.title}</td>
              <td>{book.author}</td>
              <td>{book.category}</td>
              <td>{book.price}</td>
              <td>
                <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => handleDelete(book.id)}>
                  Delete
                </Button>{" "}
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
};

const BookList = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    api
      .get("/books")
      .then((response) => setBooks(response.data))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  const handleBookAdded = (newBook) => {
    // Update the book list with the new book
    const updatedBooks = [...books, newBook];
    setBooks(updatedBooks);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Add Book component */}
      {/* ... */}

      {/* Book Table component */}
      <BookTable books={books} updateBooks={handleBookAdded} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BookList;
```

Both these components are placed in another parent component called Home.jsx.

What I need to know is how can I get the table to populate , once a data is added without me having to manually refresh the browser ?